# Turn off Amazon EC2/RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am in the process of learning more about Amazon AWS.  I want to turn off my Amazon Elastic Beanstalk EC2/RDS services.  I have selected the minimum service entries, but I am still racking up small service charges. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

> have selected the minimum service entries, but I am still racking up
>   small service charges.

It isn't clear what you are saying with that sentence. Do you mean to say that you are within the limits of the free tier and yet you are still getting charged?

If you want to just "turn off" your EC2 and RDS instances then delete/terminate them. Afterwards look at the EBS snapshots and volumes, and the RDS snapshots and delete any of those that are still there. That will most likely stop the charges.

If you want to know exactly what you are being charged for so that you can zero in on the culprit you can enable detailed billing.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has pretty good documentation on setting up and terminating instances. Here's a page with instructions on how to terminate an environment using the AWS Management Console:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.terminating.html.